# Where to put BlocProvider in my Flutter Widget Tree?

Tags: flutter, repository, state, bloc

I'm using the flutter_bloc (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc#) and I'm not able to understand where should I put my BlocProvider in my Widget Tree.

I generally prefer to put it in such a way as to wrap the Material App Widget, but many tend to put it deeper into the Widget Tree. 
In that case, I should pass my repository from widget to widget, so why should I put the BlocProvider very deep?

In the code below I put an example of how I organize the code. In this way, I don't have to pass the bloc repository into some deep widgets.

```
void main() {

final PostRepository _postRepository = PostRepository();

  return runApp(MyApp(postRepository: _postRepository));
}


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  final PostRepository postRepository;

  MyApp({this.postRepository});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<PostBloc>(
      builder: (context) => PostBloc(postRepository: postRepository),
      child: MaterialApp(
       title: 'Infinite List',
       debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       home: HomePage(),
       theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red
    ),
  ),
);
}}
```

Comment: It's up to you. BlocProvider does not rebuild whole child widget tree on changes, only consumers are rebuilt. There is a case where you might want to move BlocProvider closer to it's consumer: if you want Bloc to be disposed as soon as consumer is disposed. And in general there is no difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to put Provider/BlocProvider in the widget tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498841/where-to-put-provider-blocprovider-in-the-widget-tree)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where BlocProvider is called as long as the widget that will consume the bloc is within the scope of the BlocProvider.

```dart
BlocProvider.value(
  value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
  child: ScreenA(),  // Let ScreenA() contains widget children
);
```

Then inside `ScreenA` you can retrieve `BlocA` with

```dart
// with extensions
context.read<BlocA>();

// without extensions
BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context);
```