# Where to put Provider/BlocProvider in the widget tree?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-bloc

At this moment I think the best place to put them is when you create a route. That is because I can easily mock navigator push call. But I'm confused of what I should do when I have some sort of TabScreen with 3 different separate screens which we usually implement without routes. If I put Providers separately into places when we create tabviews, I mean structure will be like that `tabs:[ProvidersForScreen1(Screen1), ProvidersForScreen2(Screen2)...]`, then it seems like we get features in isolation and that's good BUT in that case I can not create TabScreen to test it, because Providers are created inside TabScreen and I can't mock them. Could someone tell me better approaches if you have?

Comment: Why not just wrap the app and provide all of them at the top level?

Comment: @user18309290 that's a bad practice because then it will never dispose, it can be accessed in any point of the app by no reason

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb you should place each provider at the closest parent. For example, if you have to access something from a value in a provider from all 3 different screens, place the value provider `Foo` at the parent of all 3 screens.

You still can have your screen-specific providers, wrapping each screen in your `TabScreen`. Optionally, you can have your screen-specific providers listen and react to the changes in the parent's value provider `Foo`, when you need.

For testing, you could test your `TabScreen` and individual screens separately. When testing the `TabScreen`, mock the shared provider `Foo`, and continue to use real instances of the screen-specific providers (side note: if you have API calls in the screen-specific providers, remember to wrap your `TabScreen` with a provider of a mock repository, assuming you call your repository method to make an API call). Likewise, you can test individual screens as usual by wrapping each of them with a provider of a mock instance.

The key is to always put providers as the parent of your view widgets, so that you can wrap your view widgets with providers of mock instances. I have an [example repository](https://github.com/yshean/spacex_demo) that shows how I separate the pages and the views in the `view` folder of each feature, where each `page` class only contains the providers and the `view` class, and the `view` only consumes them. This makes it easier to test your views by wrapping them with a provider that contains mocks.